# How to make NextJS Image component 100% height and width for its parent div?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

As title, I am struggling to make `Image` behave like `img`, anyone know how to make `Image` achieve like `img` does as the example below?

```
  <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", display: "flex" }}>
    {/* img */}
    <div style={{ width: "50%", height: "100%", background: "red" }}>
      <img
        src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/00/94/69/360_F_300946931_kSR84OqudEhsmBZH47HU6ud7aZIDMjEx.jpg"
        alt=""
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", objectFit: "cover" }}
      />
    </div>
    {/* Image */}
    <div style={{ width: "50%", height: "100%", background: "blue" }}>
      <Image
        src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/00/94/69/360_F_300946931_kSR84OqudEhsmBZH47HU6ud7aZIDMjEx.jpg"
        alt=""
        width="1"
        height="1"
        layout="responsive"
        objectFit="cover"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Output:
[image: example image]

**#UPDATE**
This is the answer.

```
      {/* Image */}
      <div
        style={{
          width: "50%",
          height: "100%",
          background: "blue",
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/00/94/69/360_F_300946931_kSR84OqudEhsmBZH47HU6ud7aZIDMjEx.jpg"
          alt=""
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
        />
      </div>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I see that you want the image to take the width and height of its parent element, you can just use `layout="fill"` instead of `responsive`, which causes the image to expand to fill its parent element.

Something like this:

```
<div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
  <Image
    alt='Mountains'
    src='/mountains.jpg'
    layout='fill'
    objectFit='contain'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the `layout="fill"` result, it seems it will expand to `100vw` instead of the parent container, did you add some extra codes too?

Comment: I have updated the answer, check if it works now

Comment: I have tried your new code, it still doesn't work. You can check the output screenshot in the OP.

Comment: Change display: relative to position: relative, as in my code. :)

Comment: Thanks! it works like the `img` now, tho the `objectFit` should be the same as the one on `img`, and somehow the one using `Image` got a way worse image quality than the `img` one.

Comment: Just found that there is a quality parameter for `Image` component, the issue is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Give it's parent a display of block

and take out the width and height properties preset

```
 <div style={{ width: "50%", height: "100%", background: "blue",display: "block" }}>
  <Image
    src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/00/94/69/360_F_300946931_kSR84OqudEhsmBZH47HU6ud7aZIDMjEx.jpg"
    alt=""
    layout="responsive"
    objectFit="cover"
  />
</div>
```

you can check the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization)

Comment: I tried to change the parent element to `display :block`, and the result still remind the same. Also, the `Image` component have to have `width` and `height` parameter, there isn't a `auto` option either.

Comment: *unless you are using the `layout="fill"` , but it doesn't work either

Comment: with the layout property  height and width is optional